# Granting user enough privileges to run ifconfig on IllumOS (OmniOS)

Tags: permissions, solaris, ifconfig, illumos

I sense this should be a very simple question, but somehow I cannot find a solution.

I have a non-root user and I would like to grant this user enough permissions or privileges, so he can run ifconfig (I have root access to the machine).

For example:

```
ifconfig e1000g2 plumb
ifconfig e1000g2 inet 10.0.100.4
```

Right now I get this error:

```
ifconfig: cannot plumb e1000g2: Insufficient user authorizations
```

Note: I know that I should use `ipadm` and I do, but I am interested to this particular problem with `ifconfig` :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `sudo` and `pfexec` were made for. =)

For `sudo`, you should run `visudo -s` and add an entry like this

```
myuser ALL=(ALL) /usr/sbin/ifconfig
```

Save and quit, and you're done. It's the easiest one of the two.

The more Solaris-y way is to use `pfexec`. It is more involved, but you can find directions for the process in this article: 
[Custom Roles Using RBAC in the Solaris OS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/security/custom-roles-rbac-jsp-140865.html)

For bite-sized chunks on the configuration of sudoers, I'd look here at the [Sudoers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers) entry in the Ubuntu Wiki.